# I want to add Dynamic Swing Component with or without DB value in Jframe?

Tags: java, swing

I have placed all components marked in red in one `JPanel`. The content above it is  in separate panel. 
Is it possible to display panel dynamically with or without data? 
Even DB call is successfully done and data is also fetched, but i want it after button click it may appear on Frame.

[image]

Comment: Yes...it is possible. Just place the components into another JPanel then add the Panel to your JFrame Form where you want it located. Set its visible property to false. When you want to display it then set its visible property to true. Also, your **"Do you want to add"** prompt dialog should be a Confirm Dialog instead of just a Message Dialog.

Comment: Thanks @DevilsHnd it worked properly. Thank you very much.!!

Comment: Better to use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). In this case, one of two panels would be empty, the other would contain the labels & controls.